# Problem in R-markdown to pdf_document2 on using ggVennDiagram: cache conflict?

Tags: r, caching, r-markdown, r-sp, venn-diagram

I have recently made the addition of Venn-diagrams in my document using ggVennDiagram, which facilitates its arrangement with other ggplot2 objects.

The thing is, now whenever I knit the file I encounter this error/warning and R gets stuck:

"Found more than one class "Polygon" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'sp'
Also defined by 'ggVennDiagram'.

I have tried unloading those packages that may use sp, the thing is, this package does not get loaded at all in my code and it appears not to be a dependency for the other packages.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Thank you

P.S.: I feel this may be enough for the question, but let me know if you need more. Just to clarify, I am using the following packages:

"tidyverse", "reshape2", "readxl", "knitr", "adegenet", "poppr", "pegas", "ape", "ggOceanMaps", "RColorBrewer", "lattice", "viridisLite", "pcadapt", "colorBlindness", "here", "diveRsity", "ggpubr", "vcfR", "MCMCpack", "maps", "kableExtra", "ggnewscale")

Here is an example in Rmd:

````
---
title: "Cache issue"
author: "Estevez-Barcia, Daniel"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    fig_crop: no
header-includes:
 \usepackage{float}
 \floatplacement{table}{H}
 \floatplacement{figure}{H}
 \newcommand{\beginsupplement}{\setcounter{table}{0}  \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}} \setcounter{figure}{0} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}}
---

```{r setup}
#| include=FALSE

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, # set up the default params for chunks
                      fig.pos = "H",
                      fig.width= 8,
                      fig.height= 7,
                      tab.pos = "H",
                      collapse = TRUE,
                      message = FALSE,
                      warning = FALSE,
                      comment = "#>"
)

knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file()) # specify the project root to take files
options(knitr.kable.NA = "---") # change the NA in kable tables for ---
```

```{r load-first}
#| include=FALSE, 
#| echo=FALSE

## Packages to load and other characteristics

packages <- c("tidyverse", "reshape2", "readxl", "knitr", "adegenet", "poppr", 
              "pegas", "ape", "ggOceanMaps", "RColorBrewer", "lattice", "viridisLite", 
              "pcadapt", "colorBlindness", "here", "diveRsity", "ggpubr", "vcfR", "MCMCpack", 
              "maps", "kableExtra", "ggnewscale")

installed_packages <- packages %in% rownames(installed.packages())
if (any(installed_packages == FALSE)) {
  install.packages(packages[!installed_packages])
}

invisible(lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE))

# Set custom theme for ggplot
ggtheme = theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size=12),
                axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size=12, angle = 90),
                axis.title = element_text(colour="black", size=12),
                panel.border = element_rect(colour="black", fill=NA, size=1),
                panel.background = element_blank(),
                plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=15) 
)

# Additional libraries

library(cowplot)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(hierfstat)

```

```{r venn-diagram}
#| echo=FALSE,
#| include= FALSE

randomPlot <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = drat, color = cyl)) +
  geom_point()

a <- c("Ramón", "Marta", "Inés", "John", "Michael", "Diego", "Carmen", "Aidara", "Sofía")
b <- c("Ramón", "Marta", "Pablo", "Paloma", "Einar", "Lykke", "Carmen", "Ester", "Sofía", "Knute")
ggVenn <- ggVennDiagram::ggVennDiagram(x = list(a, b), label_alpha = 0,
              category.names = c("Names1", "Names2"), label = "count") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

```{r quick map}
#| echo=FALSE

dt <- data.frame(lon = c(-30, -30, 30, 30), lat = c(50, 80, 80, 50))
basemap(data = dt, bathymetry = TRUE) + 
  geom_polygon(data = transform_coord(dt), aes(x = lon, y = lat), color = "red", fill = NA)
  
```

```{r plot}
#| echo=FALSE

ggarrange(randomPlot, ggVenn, nrow = 2)
```
````

Comment: I understand your plight, but it's a bit difficult to reproduce without a little more information. Are you able to provide a rudimentary reprex that (1) isn't humongous, and (2) still causes the error?

Comment: I will try to provide a case: bear in mind that this problem only happens to me when knitting, not in a independent script.

Comment: A reprex can be an Rmd file to knit ...

Comment: I have kind of solved the issue (see the updated question). I created the VennDiagram for plotting later, in between the creation of said object and the actual plotting there is a map. It is when producing the map that the error occurs.

Comment: Just to make it sure: there is now a Rmd code in the question that produces the error

Comment: You likely won't get much response when your previous comment says *"I have kind of solved the issue"*. As for me, I'm not about to install all of those packages, most of which do not appear to be used by the code, sorry (there's a practical limit for me). Good luck.

Comment: The packages are included there in case the error originates from conflicts between them (in the whole document, that I am not going to share, these are used). For all I see this may not be the issue. I am not forcing anyone to install the packages but rather showing the code that is producing the error including all the packages that I use in the document.